# How to create mutual Cascading dropdown in Angular 6+ (country <--> city)

Tags: angular, dropdown

I found a lot of examples about how to create Cascading drop-down that select country and filter the state. But Is there a way to do mutual dependent filtering.

Like we can from the country list and filter city and also can from city list filter country.

Because right now, I have two drop-down menus and the data in the two drop-down menus is related. The function I want to achieve is that when I select one element in the first (or second) dropdown menu. In the second (or first) dropdown, the element is related to the menu will be highlighted.

I include the design here in case my explanation is unclear.

Thank you in advance for any help. I am new in learning Angular. Any advice will be appreciated!

**Dropdown menu design :**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a demonstration project at [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zawkv7). I used first and  last names because it was easier for me to make up data. My code basically consists of three files. Here is app.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { Person } from "./Person";

@Component({
    selector: "my-app",
    templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
    styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
name = "Angular";
people: Person[] = [
    { firstName: "john", lastName: "smith" },
    { firstName: "john", lastName: "pane" },
    { firstName: "john", lastName: "sander" },
    { firstName: "joe", lastName: "smith" },
    { firstName: "joe", lastName: "pane" },
    { firstName: "joe", lastName: "sander" },
    { firstName: "sue", lastName: "smith" },
    { firstName: "sue", lastName: "pane" },
    { firstName: "sue", lastName: "sander" },
    { firstName: "alice", lastName: "smith" },
    { firstName: "alice", lastName: "pane" },
    { firstName: "alice", lastName: "sander" },
    { firstName: "sally", lastName: "smith" },
    { firstName: "fred", lastName: "smith" },
    { firstName: "ted", lastName: "smith" },
    { firstName: "karl", lastName: "jones" },
    { firstName: "karl", lastName: "dowd" },
    { firstName: "tom", lastName: "brown" }
];
firstNameSet = new Set<string>();
lastNameSet = new Set<string>();
ngOnInit() {
    this.people.forEach(person => this.firstNameSet.add(person.firstName));
    this.people.forEach(person => this.lastNameSet.add(person.lastName));
}
firstChanged(event) {
    let first = event.target.value;
    this.lastNameSet.clear();
    let firstArray = this.people.filter(person => person.firstName === first);
    firstArray.forEach(person => this.lastNameSet.add(person.lastName));
}
lastChanged(event) {
    let last = event.target.value;
    this.firstNameSet.clear();
    let lastArray = this.people.filter(person => person.lastName === last);
    lastArray.forEach(person => this.firstNameSet.add(person.firstName));
}
reset(firstSelect, lastSelect) {
    firstSelect.selectedIndex = 0;
    lastSelect.selectedIndex = 0;
    this.people.forEach(person => this.firstNameSet.add(person.firstName));
    this.people.forEach(person => this.lastNameSet.add(person.lastName));
}
}
```

Here is app.component.html

```
    <hello name="{{ name }}"></hello>
<form>
    <select #firstSelect (change)="firstChanged($event)">
        <option value="firstName">firstName</option>
        <option *ngFor="let first of firstNameSet;" value="{{first}}">
            {{first}}</option>
    </select>
    <select #lastSelect (change)="lastChanged($event)">
        <option value="lastName">lastName</option>
        <option *ngFor="let last of lastNameSet;" value="{{last}}">
            {{last}}</option>
    </select>
    <button type="button" (click)="reset(firstSelect, lastSelect)">Reset</button
 </form>
```

and here is Person.ts

```
    export interface Person {
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

html file

```
 <label>Country:</label> 
    <select [(ngModel)]="selectedCountry.id" (change)="onSelect($event.target.value)">
      <option value="0">--Select--</option>
      <option *ngFor="let country of countries" value= {{country.id}}>{{country.name}}</option>
    </select>

<div>
<label>State:</label>
<select>
  <option value="0">--Select--</option>
  <option *ngFor="let state of states " value= {{state.id}}>{{state.name}}</option>
</select>
</div>
```

service file

```
getCountries() {
    return [
     new Country(1, 'USA' ),
     new Country(2, 'India' ),
    ];
  }

  getStates() {
   return [
     new State(1, 1, 'Arizona' ),
     new State(2, 1, 'Alaska' ),
     new State(3, 1, 'Florida'),
     new State(4, 1, 'Hawaii'),
     new State(5, 2, 'Delhi' ),
     new State(6, 2, 'Kerala'),
     new State(7, 2, 'Mumbai' )
    ];
  }
```

ts file

```
countries: Country[];
  states: State[];

  constructor(private selectService: SelectService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.countries = this.selectService.getCountries();
    this.onSelect(this.selectedCountry.id);
  }

  onSelect(countryid) {
    this.states = this.selectService.getStates().filter((item) => item.countryid == countryid);
  }
```